# Missing closing <tr> tag

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

A partial view that I have is throwing an error:

```
{"Encountered end tag \"tr\" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?\r\n"}
```

I cannot find where the tag is not closed. I have spent a significant amount of time trying to find the error, to no avail.

I am relatively positive it has to do with the code elements I have in the view, but I am unable to pinpoint it.

This is the Razor view.

```
@{
    DateTime dateValue;
}

<div class="table-responsive">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkallMaster" />
    <table id="reportTable" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;">Variable Investment Option</th>
                <th>Unit Value<br /><span style="font-weight: normal;">@Model.Start.ToString("dddd, M/d/yyyy")</span></th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Select Values<br />To Download<br /><input type="checkbox"  /></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Output.Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">@row.ItemArray[1].ToString();</td>
                    <td align="right" width="50px;">@row.ItemArray[2].ToString();</div></td>
                    <td align="center">
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(row.ItemArray[3].ToString(), out dateValue))
                    {
                        @Html.Raw(dateValue.ToString("M/d/yyyy"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.Raw("N/A");
                    }
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="FundCodes" value="@row.ItemArray[0].ToString()" class="checkall" /> </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So, What's your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing a `div` in the middle of a `td`:

```
<td align="right" width="50px;">@row.ItemArray[2].ToString();</div></td>
```

This is going to try to close the `div` that contains the whole table, which means the table structure bleeds out from the `div`.  Anything thereafter is going to be undefined and essentially a markup error.

Also note that you don't need semi-colons to terminate your Razor syntax statements.  I imagine those are actually going to render to the browser as semi-colons, which you probably don't want.

Comment: Amazing! I don't know how long I have stared at this. Thanks. I will try it out when I get back to the office and mark as an answer.